# Eigenvalues of a $A^T A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the matrix of order $1\times{n}$,  $A=(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ , where $a_i$ are real;
The question is to find all eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

I have proved that it is a non-invertible matrix, therefore $0$ is one of the values.
And the product matrix is an $nxn$ matrix with the diagonal elements being $a_1^2, a_2^2,...,a_n^2$.
I am struggling with finding the other eigenvalues, tried by calculating the det of $A - aI$, but didn't go anywhere.

Comment: Your might check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137885/show-some-eigenvalue-properties-for-a-xy.  I left an answer there which I believe addresses your question.

Comment: Also, by "A(transpose)*" do you mean $(A^T)^* = A^\dagger$?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I think the * is probably supposed to indicate multiplication.

Comment: @RobertLewis By that I mean multiplying A transpose with A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A^tA = \begin{pmatrix}
   a_1a_1 & a_1a_2 & a_1a_3 & \dots   & a_1a_n\\
   a_2a_1 & a_2 a_2 & a_2a_3 & \dots & a_2a_n \\
   \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
   a_na_1 & a_na_2 & a_na_3 & \dots & a_na_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

All the columns can be obtained by mutiplying by a scalar the first column, so $rank(A^tA)=1$. So $0$ is an eigen value with multiplicity $n-1$. The sum of eigen values is equal to the trace of the matrix, thus you can easily find the last eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you very much; this has been the most helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose that $v$ is an $n \times 1$ vector orthogonal to $A$ (or more precisely, $w$ is a $1 \times n$ vector orthogonal to $A$, and $v = w^t$). What do you get when you compute $A^{*}Av$?

Comment: Thanks for your time! I managed to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the definition of an eigenvalue / eigenvector pair,
$$
A^T A v = \lambda v.
$$
Now extend $A$ to an orthogonal basis: so let $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ be an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $A_1 = A^T$. Write $v$ in this basis:
$$
v = a_1 A^T + a_2 A_2 + a_3 A_3 + \cdots + a_n A_n.
$$

Then,
$$
A^T Av = a_1 A^T A A^T + a_2 A^T A A_2 + a_3 A^T A A_3 + \cdots + a_n A^T A A_n.
$$

Because the basis is orthogonal, $A A_k = 0$ for any $k \ge 2$. Also $A A^T$ = $\|A\|^2$. So this just reduces to
$$
A^T A v = a_1 A^T \|A\|^2.
$$
The only way this can be equal to $\lambda v$ is if $\lambda = 0$ and the component $a_1 = 0$, or if $\lambda = \|A\|^2$ and the components $a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$ are all $0$.

So the only eigenvalues are $0$ and $\|A\|^2$, and we get the corresponding eigenvectors as well.